# loading pic in xaml web browser.

Tags: c#, xaml

```
 <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <phone:WebBrowser x:Name="browser" IsScriptEnabled="True" Margin="-12,0,-11,0" />
    </Grid>
```

I initialized web browser using this code. Since, my html content is too big, it takes much more to load those html files. Till the html files displayed, web browser is being white color.

It makes me irritate. I need to know can we have any loader pic in web browser. So, the pic displayed until web browser loads the html files ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't verify this at the moment but the approach I would take is to display an image via Image or some alternative, such as a loading message in XAML, and set the initial visibility of this stand-in to visible and the WebBrowser to collapsed.

Implement an event handler for the LoadCompleted event on the WebBrowser and when it is triggered, swap the visibility states to hide the progress/wait message and show the web browser.

It'll look roughly like:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <TextBlock Text="Loading... please wait" Visibility="Visibile" x:Name="loadingMessage"/>
    <phone:WebBrowser x:Name="browser" IsScriptEnabled="True" Margin="-12,0,-11,0" LoadCompleted="htmlLoadCompleted" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
</Grid>

// In the code behind - HTML finished loading, swap visibility to show the page
private void htmlLoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    loadingMessage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    browser.Visibility = Visibility.Visibile;
}
```

I have concerns over when/how the WebBrowser starts loading, which is why I'd like to caution I don't have a local environment configured to verify this approach is 100% working. You might need to experiment with this some to get it working but I hope this helps set you on the right path.

Comment: Since i am very new to xaml, can u pls explain that via code ?

Comment: Elaborated answer with some code. See if you can get this approach working, and if not I'll see if I can assist more. Good luck

Comment: Well it works, but with some bugs. It shows the text first, but rapidly it disappears, then as usual browser initialized with blank screen as earlier.